# Is it possible to use one allocation for a chain of renderscript actions?

Tags: android, renderscript

For example I make an allocation from a bitmap, then aplly to it the brightnessContrastRs() and then some different filter with similar implementation on that allocation, changed by brightnessContrastRs() action?

```
public Bitmap brightnessContrastRs(Bitmap bmIn, int brightness, int contrast)
{
    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmIn.getWidth(), bmIn.getHeight(),
            bmIn.getConfig());
    Allocation allocIn;
    allocIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bmIn,
            Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
            Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    Allocation allocOut = Allocation.createTyped(rs, allocIn.getType());

    scriptCBrightnessContrast.set_in(allocIn);
    allocIn.destroy();
    scriptCBrightnessContrast.set_out(allocOut);
    scriptCBrightnessContrast.set_script(scriptCBrightnessContrast);
    float rowContrast = ((100.0f + contrast) * (100.0f + contrast) / 10000.0f);
    float rowBrightness = brightness / 255.f;
    scriptCBrightnessContrast.set_rowBrightness(rowBrightness);
    scriptCBrightnessContrast.set_rowContrast(rowContrast);
    scriptCBrightnessContrast.invoke_filter();
    allocOut.copyTo(bmOut);
    allocOut.destroy();
    return bmOut;
}
```

the RS script:

```
rs_allocation out;
rs_allocation in;
rs_script script;

float rowBrightness;
float rowContrast;

void root(const uchar4* v_in, uchar4* v_out, const void* usrData, uint32_t x,
          uint32_t y)
{
   float4 current = rsUnpackColor8888(*v_in);

   current.r = clamp(((clamp(current.r + rowBrightness, 0.0f, 1.0f) - 0.5f) * rowContrast + 0.5f), 0.0f, 1.0f);
   current.g = clamp(((clamp(current.g + rowBrightness, 0.0f, 1.0f)- 0.5f) * rowContrast + 0.5f), 0.0f, 1.0f);
   current.b = clamp(((clamp(current.b + rowBrightness, 0.0f, 1.0f) - 0.5f) * rowContrast + 0.5f), 0.0f, 1.0f);

   *v_out = rsPackColorTo8888(current.r, current.g, current.b, current.a);
}
void filter()
{
    #if !defined(RS_VERSION) || (RS_VERSION < 14)
       rsForEach(script, in, out, 0);
    #else
       rsForEach(script, in, out);
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking if you can pass an Allocation around like that and have things work, yes, you can certainly do that. However, you can't destroy allocIn that early, because it still needs to be used by the script when it's launched.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a ScriptGroup instead.